# Why would execution results of Idea's Run mode and Debug mode differ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In a dual-stack network environment, obtain the corresponding IP address based on the domain name.

```java
public static void getIP() throws UnknownHostException, InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "false");
    // prefer IPv6
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "true");
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("www.baidu.com");
    System.out.println("inetAddress="+inetAddress.toString()); 
    if(inetAddress instanceof Inet6Address){
        // When using Debug mode, execute here
        System.out.println("IPv6="+inetAddress.getHostAddress()); 
    }else if(inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address){
        // When using Run mode, execute here
        System.out.println("IPv4="+inetAddress.getHostAddress());
    }
}
```

The above code returns an IPv4 address when run in Idea's Run mode, but when run in Debug mode, the correct IPv6 address is returned. What is the problem?

The operating environment is OS: ubuntu, JDK: jdk8, and I have tried many times with the same result.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior with your code and the information you have provided.  In any scenario I run I get ipv4.  I am also running a dual stack

Comment: I can't reproduce either. How is the run/debug configuration for your program set up in IDEA? Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.